# Manipulate regular String in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String text that has a regular form and want to take two parts of this String.
the String has the format

```
"<html><div style=\"text-align:center;\"><b>****</b><br><i>Aula: </i><b>****</b></div></html>"
```

Where the `****`indicates the parts of string that I want to take.
How can I do?
I'm using JAVA, also the string is written in HTML.

We can see that the intresting parts of the String are both limited by `<b>` and `<\b>`

Comment: use an Html parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is **exactly** form of your HTML String then you can use substring method using positions of `<b>` and `</b>` (if your HTML code can change you should use HTML parser)

```
String s = "<html><div style=\"text-align:center;\"><b>first</b><br><i>Aula: </i><b>second</b></div></html>";
int start = s.indexOf("<b>");
int end = s.indexOf("</b>");
String firstMatch = s.substring(start + "<b>".length(), end);

//now we can start looking for next `<b>` after position where we found `</b>`
start = s.indexOf("<b>", end);
//and look for </b> after position that we found latest <b>
end = s.indexOf("</b>", start);
String secondMatch = s.substring(start + "<b>".length(), end);

System.out.println(firstMatch);
System.out.println(secondMatch);
```

output:

```
first
second
```

Comment: Thanks, that will be good for the first interesting word. And how can I take the second? Even the second one, infact, bengins and ends with <b> </b>

Comment: @Bernheart Sorry I didn't notice that there are two parts that need to be extracted. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you for explain.  That is what I wanted!

Comment: @Bernheart, You can also use `lastIndexOf()` for the second `<b>`. A matter of taste though but just something you should read up on. You never know when it might come handy.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options.  The most obvious, but probably not the best, is to use a regex.  Look at [String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for that.

A better option is to use an HTML parser.  An example of that is [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: You shouldn't use a regex to parse HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1864167

Comment: You shouldn't be suggesting `replaceAll()` when OP clearly wants to parse data out of the string. I wonder if people have stopped reading answers before voting it up.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal no need to be rude.  You can use `replaceAll` to do that.

Comment: @tieTYT, please add an illustration. It would help me as well.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal `System.out.println("<html><div style=\"text-align:center;\"><b>****</b><br><i>Aula: </i><b>****</b></div></html>".replaceAll("<html><div style=\"text-align:center;\"><b>", "").replaceAll("</b></div></html>", ""));`

Comment: @tieTYT, first of all there are two `<b>` values that need to be parsed. Your solution leaves `****</b><br><i>Aula: </i><b>****` as output which is incorrect. Secondly, almost always you would parse something known out of something unknown. Your solution of passing a known header and footer is just plain hacky and impractical.

Comment: My mistake.  Just add another `replaceAll("</b><br><i>Aula: </i><b>", "")` on the end.  Yes it's hacky.  That's why I said, "probably not the best"  That's why I said a **better** option is to use JSoup.